# Windows. Постоянно сбивается системное время и дата

Tags: windows

В логах Kernel General:

Вот, что я уже попробовал:

1. bcdedit /set {default} USEPLATFORMCLOCK on
2. Включение и отключение синхронизации
3. Включение и отключение "службы времени Windows"
4. Установка обновления часовых поясов
5. Удаление всех ненужных программ
6. Запрет на смену времени для Local Service в локальных политиках
7. Проверка антивирусом
8. Настройка Windows для работы по UTC

Пояс правильный (обновление установлено), синхронизация отключена.
Ранее компьютер был в домене, сейчас в рабочей группе.

Comment: Планировщик смотрели? Есть какая-то закономерность сбива времени? В системный лог пишется событие о смене времени?

Comment: у тебя батарейка в биосе сдохла, по ходу. И время сбивается когда комп вырубаешь :)

Comment: ...и из-за зачем-то отключённой синхронизации оно так и остается сбитым

Comment: В планировщике проверял, ничего.В логах написано: "системное время изменено" (инициатор Kernel-General), дело не в батарейке т.к. часы сбиваются при постоянном поступлении питания.